# How do I get the result of UUID() in a PHP var?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't for the live of me figure out how to get the result of a simple UUID() query into a variable/echo it/whatever.

```
$query = "SELECT UUID()";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    $appuserid = var_dump($result);
}
```

`vardump` of result:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
    ["current_field"]=> int(0)
    ["field_count"]=> int(1)
    ["lengths"]=> NULL
    ["num_rows"]=> int(1)
    ["type"]=> int(0)
}
```

Help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Try using `UUID() as uuid`, that may help.

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you running this query?  How are you getting the results?  Have you tried to `var_dump()` the result set to see what fields you have?

Comment: @RocketHazmat What do you mean? I've used it to INSERT fields, but need it on the PHP side as a variable for future operations.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah I've tried vardump and got "object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }" Don't know how to access the actual string.

Comment: Well, you didn't describe your issue or what you are doing in your question, so I just guessed at a solution.  You need to give *details* about your issue, so we understand what you are doing.  Anyway, if you want to get a value from the database, you're going to need to `SELECT` it.  All `INSERT` does is *insert* a row, it does not give you back any of the values.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right, sorry - I appreciate your help! Here's what I'm currently trying  $query = "SELECT UUID()";
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
  $appuserid = var_dump($result);
 }

Comment: First off, `var_dump()` doesn't return anything, so your `$appuserid` will not contain anything.  Second, you need to *fetch* the results after running the query.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @dpetrov Please **edit** the question to add information. Don't scatter it in comments, where code is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

you are mostly there

```
$uuid = $mysqli->query("SELECT uuid()")->fetch_row()[0];
```

Comment: Not sure why you decided to write ten times more code than needed, but I left only what's really needed

Comment: because i generally access mysqli via a helper class that handles all the nicities of preparing a statements, binding the params error handling , etc and was a little to rushed to completely rewrite so i just trimmed down the helper class to mimimum to get it working

Comment: Just for your info, the code you've got was unusable due to some errors. foreach with unconditional return inside is rather questionable move. By the way, "error handling" is probably redundant, given mysqli nowadays reports its errors by itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` that you can send immediately after an `INSERT`, but that won't work for bulk-inserts, and it's for an auto_increment primary key.

It may be more useful to generate the UUID within your own code, with a library such as [ramsey/uuid](https://packagist.org/packages/ramsey/uuid), and send that in with the rest of the data to be inserted. You can then simply use the variable you already have.